# Possible to send username that we use in session?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send the user id that is stored in a session variable. When the user submits a form, the database should receive the data that the user submits and also get the userid from the database. Here is what I have:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']));

{

header('Location: index.php');

}

<p>Welcome, <b>  echo $_SESSION['username'];</b>


if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = 'root';

$dbpass = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn )

{

die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )

{

$complaint = addslashes ($_POST['complaint']);

}

else

{

$complaint = $_POST['complaint'];

}$sql = "INSERT INTO employee ".

"(complaint) ".

"VALUES('$complaint')";

mysql_select_db('sistempinjaman');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )

{

die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());

}

echo "You complaint sent. We will respon soon via email  \n";

mysql_close($conn);

}
```

Can username be sent with submit form?

When we want display data, the table will have:

```
| username | complaint |
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You can send username in session. But what is the problem?

Comment: you can also use hidden field and set that hidden field value as whatever session you want inside form and u done.

Comment: @usman. this coding is correct?

Comment: What is error you are getting?. Then people here will answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for advice. problem slove :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are all the fields you have in `employee` table? add `username` field if it is not there and store the username which is stored in SESSION.

Example:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO employee (username,complaint) 
         VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."','".$complaint."')";
```

Comment: now i have username and employee. can make correction my coding? i still blur. im sorry

Comment: What is the problem to use above query?

Comment: LearneR your query is useful. before this I dont know to use  insert in VALUES "$_SESSION['username'] ". thats why i dont know to  send 'username'. btw thanks for your help sir :)